# How to add multiple text file in a single zip file through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix, sh

I have multiple text files residing in a single folder. These files are created on daily basis with time stamp on it like ABC_set_05082020.txt, DEF_set_050820202.txt. I want to create a single folder like destination_05082020.zip in same directory which contains all these files.

The Script i created is like

```
FILE_DIR1=home/users/documents/Files
FILE_NAME=$1
FILE_DATE_TIME1="${FILE_NAME}_set_`date +%Y%m%d`"
FULL_PATH1="${FILE_DIR1}${FILE_DATE_TIME1}.dat"

if [ $# -lt 1 ]  
then
echo "*************************************************************************"
echo "* ERROR script requires <workbookname> "
echo "*************************************************************************"
exit $EXIT_SYS_ERROR
fi

if [ "$FILE_NAME" = "ABC" ]
then
zip -r $FILE_DIR1/destination.zip $FULL_PATH1

fi

# done
printf "$SCRIPT_NAME `date`: Info. Complete Successfully, exitings |$RC|.\n"
exit $EXIT_SUCCESS
```

here i am able to create destination.zip in the same directory and destination.zip also contains ABC_set_05082020.txt but when i am unzipping destination.zip. It contains complete folder path like home/users/documents/files/ABC_set_05082020.txt. I don't want complete path in it when i unzip it. It should only contain my Text file. please help.

Comment: Try `man zip` and you will see following entry `-D
       --no-dir-entries
              Do not create entries in the zip archive for directories.`

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same result. destination.zip contains complete structure home/users/documents/files and then ABC_set_05082020.txt

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
zip -rj $FILE_DIR1/destination.zip $FULL_PATH1
```

From `man` page

> -j
>          --junk-paths
>                 Store  just  the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full
>                 path (relative to the current directory).

Demo:

```
$zip -jr test.zip /home/renegade/test/file*
  adding: file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file2.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file3.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file4.txt (stored 0%)
$zip -r test_2.zip /home/renegade/test/file*
  adding: home/renegade/test/file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: home/renegade/test/file2.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: home/renegade/test/file3.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: home/renegade/test/file4.txt (stored 0%)
$unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   file1.txt
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   file2.txt
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   file3.txt
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   file4.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     4 files
$unzip -l test_2.zip
Archive:  test_2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   home/renegade/test/file1.txt
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   home/renegade/test/file2.txt
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   home/renegade/test/file3.txt
        0  2020-05-09 05:50   home/renegade/test/file4.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     4 files
$
```

Edit : `-D` does not work with `-r`

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide some explanation on how it works.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not  a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can `edit` to add additional info & to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Hi @MickaelB. and @ Sherly Thank you. I have updated the post with detailed explantion and demo.